# Is there a Scala parsing solution that works on string tokens rather than characters?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, parser-combinators, parboiled, fastparse

I have a document I would like to parse one line at a time. My tokens are entire lines:

```
Pizza Is Great

12
14
17

red
blue
buckle my shoe

PS. I <3
```

I could match the above with a grammar (pseudocode) something like:

```
text     → /.*/
int      → /[0-9]+/
blank    → /^\s+$/
Document → text + blank + int* + blank + text* + blank + text
```

What I want is to send each line independently into the parser as a token and try to match it, but every solution I have tried so far ([scala-parser-combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators), [FastParse](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/fastparse/), etc.) requires me to tediously define each token *with the newline attached* in order to break it apart correctly. Clearly I don't actually want my grammar to know about the newlines; they should be used to tokenize the input before it ever hits the parser.

Is there a Scala-compatible parsing solution that can work line-by-line in this way, so that the newlines disappear from my grammar definition entirely? (Could someone show me a simple example?)

Comment: Can you split the input into lines before passing them to the parser? For example, using [`linesIterator`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/StringOps.html#linesIterator:Iterator[String]) or by reading a file line-by-line?

Comment: @TimMoore Good question. In FastParse, for instance, I can split them and send them in as an `Iterator[String]`, but it doesn't actually seem to help -- the regexes still apply across tokens, as if the input was just one long continuous string. In general, I can write an outer loop around a parser and just match single-line tokens one at a time, but then I'm basically writing the combinator piece myself. (Which maybe is the answer.)